# Determine whether $\frac{n^2}{n+1}$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis

For, $S_n=\frac{n^2}{n+1}$ , I'd like to determine whether $S_n$ is convergent or divergent using the ratio method. So this is how I proceeded:

let $\;a_n= \frac{n^2}{n+1}$ and let $\;\;a_{n+1}= \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)+1}$.

Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)+1}}{\frac{n^2}{n+1}}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)+1}\cdot{\frac{n+1}{n^2}}=\frac{(n+1)(n^2+2n+1)}{n^3+2n^2}=\frac{n^3+3n^2+3n+1}{n^3+2n^2}$

I am unsure how to proceed at this point.
Clearly the ratio is greater than 1, in which case $S_n$ diverges, but perhaps there is a simpler way other than using the ratio method in proving this?

Comment: $\frac{n^2}{n+1}>\frac{n^2-1}{n+1}=n-1$, which obviously diverges to infinity.

Comment: Also, L'Hopital's rule:  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^2}{n+1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 2n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Your argument shows that the sequence is increasing. If the sequence is bounded above it will converge. If you divide numerator and denominator by $n,$ you get that $S_n = \frac{n}{1+\frac{1}{n}}.$ Now what happens as $n \rightarrow \infty?$